# Magento 2 - custom product search function

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, custom-search, magento-product-attributes

Currently i am working on the custom product search function. Please check the image

[image]

These form already done on the frontend, using these form values i need to filter available products on the database.

**Destination** : is multiple location (Eg: Newyork, Newjercy, etc)

### So on the admin product edit page need to save below values,

```
Pickup Location : Product Available Date : Product Available Time
```

---

```
Newyork         : 20/02/2020             : 10.50

Newjercy        : 22/02/2020             : 18.30

....

....
```

Similarly,  I dont know how to save values likes this and implement this concept.

If you have an idea, share with me. Thanks in advance..!